# Bash getting escaped variable key value with script

Tags: bash, docker, jq, traefik

I want to use jq to get value's out of a the Traefik API service. The output of the service looks like this:

```
{
  "loadBalancer": {
    "servers": [
      {
        "url": "http://172.18.0.19:3000"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://172.18.0.17:3000"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://172.20.0.3:3000"
      }
    ],
    "healthCheck": {
      "path": "/health",
      "interval": "10s",
      "timeout": "10s",
      "followRedirects": true
    },
    "passHostHeader": true
  },
  "status": "enabled",
  "serverStatus": {
    "http://172.18.0.17:3000": "UP",
    "http://172.18.0.19:3000": "UP",
    "http://172.20.0.3:3000": "DOWN"
  },
  "provider": "docker",
  "type": "loadbalancer"
}
```

I want to get the value of the `serverStatus` dynamically. First assigning a variable with the correct IP address from docker inspect. I'm using `curl` with `jq` to check if the container is being serviced.

The problem is when getting it with a variable I cannot seem to escape the special characters in the url key. **Nothing is returned**.

This is the command I use is:

```
TRAEFIK_URL="http://someurl.com/"
TRAEFIK_URL="'Authorization: Basic hashkey"
NEW_IPADDRESS=$(docker container inspect some_container_name | jq -r .[].NetworkSettings.Networks.proxy.IPAddress)
NEW_ENV_URL="http://${NEW_IPADDRESS}:3000"

curl --location --request GET "$TRAEFIK_URL" --header "$TRAEFIK_AUTH_HEADER" | jq -r '.serverStatus["${NEW_ENV_URL}"]'
```

I've tried using this command and some other obvious options but all didn't work.

```
jq -r .serverStatus[$NEW_ENV_URL]
```

I do get the correct value when I'm not using a variable to get the status using:

```
 jq -r '.serverStatus["http://172.18.0.17:3000"]'
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the preferred ways to pass specific environment variables into jq is using the `--arg` command-line option; in your case:

```
jq -r --arg url "${NEW_ENV_URL}"  '.serverStatus[$url]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the option `--arg` to pass arguments to `jq`.

```
jq --arg url http://172.18.0.17:3000 -r '.serverStatus[$url]'
```

Always use this option to avoid security problems by injections.